# Angular UI Grid conditional row expand

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using Angular UI Grid and the ui-grid-expandable plugin.
Is there a way to decide for each row, if the expand button (+) is displayed?
By default it is always displayed, no matter if there is available data in the subgrid.

Thanks.

Comment: may be `getTreeState()` but it seems not working: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.treeBase.api:PublicApi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly no, there is not an option for that as of now.

You can use the following to make things work as you wish:

- remove default row headers by setting to `false` `enableExpandableRowHeader`
- adding a custom row header by calling `$scope.gridApi.core.addRowHeaderColumn`

This way you can build your own logic. I did something like that in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqvz9MxmmZitOcQ7ZZIt?p=preview).

If you need more info:

- http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/114_row_header
- http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid

Answer (score 0):

I have a pull request with UI-GRID that solves this.

You add a boolean to the subGridOptions called disableRowExpandable.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/pull/6135/commits/83ade3445711e532f689d224904babfe92c7b45e

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can !

Add to subGridOptions object this option:

```
disableRowExpandable:(condition here).
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the last version of UI GRID

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.11.0/ui-grid.min.js

Then use the property disableRowExpandable inside your subGridOptions

Here there a little example.

```
for (i = 0; i < response.data.result.length; i++) {
                    if (response.data.result[i].SubProcesos != null) {
                        response.data.result[i].subGridOptions = {
                            columnDefs: establecerColDefs(response.data.Rol),
                            data: response.data.result[i].SubProcesos,
                            disableRowExpandable: false

                        };
                    } else {
                        response.data.result[i].subGridOptions = {
                            columnDefs: [{ }],
                            data:[{}],
                            disableRowExpandable: true
                    };
                    }
                }
```

[image]